# multiple alter table in execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, execute, alter

```
BEGIN
  execute immediate '
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE EMPRESA ADD CONSTRAINT pk_empresa_id PRIMARY KEY (EMPRESA_ID);

        ALTER TABLE CLIENTE ADD CONSTRAINT pk_cliente_id PRIMARY KEY (CLIENTE_ID);
    END';
END;
```

I want to do something like this in PL/SQL, but it throws me an error.

How should I do it?

Comment: Why are you adding the same constraint twice?

Comment: @Gordon I'm sorry, it was a mistake to copy the code. corrected, thanks, but throws me an error anyway.

Comment: @RicardoValenzuela - English please

Comment: @Gurwinder
`ORA-06550: line 3, column 13:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
ORA-06512: at line 67
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you can't run DDL directly in PLSQL. You can run them in separate execute immediates:

```
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE EMPRESA ADD CONSTRAINT pk_empresa_id PRIMARY KEY (EMPRESA_ID)';
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE CLIENTE ADD CONSTRAINT pk_cliente_id PRIMARY KEY (CLIENTE_ID)';
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, now I understand better, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  column_exists exception;
  pragma exception_init (column_exists, -01430);

begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ALTER TABLE STUDENT TO ADD HISTORY_MKS, ENGLISH_MKS, MATH_MKS');
  execute immediate 'alter table STUDENT add(
    HISTORY_MKS NUMBER,
    ENGLIST_MKS NUMBER,
    MATH_MKS    NUMBER
    )';
  exception when column_exists then null;
end;
/
```

kindly change as per your needs, should work